# Xpage richTextField on a page; cannot configure skin correctly

Tags: ckeditor, xpages, xpages-extlib

Current app has a richTextField. Users will only be allowed to use a subset of the buttons (e.g. no pictures, etc).

I would like to put a nice skin on the editor now. I have added bootstrapck folder to my WebContents folder.

What is wrong. When I run this I get a very tiny field, and there are not toolbars at all.

==============================================================

OK I am adding some different code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument
            var="document1"
            formName="Cash" />
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:scriptBlock
        id="scriptBlockCKEditor">
        <xp:this.value>
            <![CDATA[
         require( ['dojo/_base/declare', 'ibm/xsp/widget/layout/xspCKEditor'], function( declare, xspCKEditor ){
            return declare( 'com.scoular.CKEDITOR', xspCKEditor, {
               constructor: function ckew_ctor(/*Object*/options){
                  CKEDITOR.timestamp = '';
               }
            });   
         });
      ]]>
        </xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
    <xp:inputRichText
        id="inputRichText2"
        value="#{document1.Body}"
        dojoType="com.scoular.CKEDITOR">
        <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:dojoAttribute
                name="toolbar">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var myToolbar = "[['Font','FontSize'], \n"
            +"['Preview', 'Bold','TextColor','BGColor'], \n"
            +"['Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript']]";
return myToolbar;}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:dojoAttribute>
            <xp:dojoAttribute
                name="enterMode"
                value="2" />
            <xp:dojoAttribute
                name="skin">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"BootstrapCK-Skin,/"+database.getFilePath()+"/BootstrapCK-Skin/"}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:dojoAttribute>
        </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
    </xp:inputRichText>
</xp:view>
```

In Chrome I get the following error.

How do I find the correct file path to the WebContents folder?
And where is the other error even coming from?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my richtext item I am using an extra dojo attribute, skin. Which points to the location of my custom skin

```
<xp:this.dojoAttributes>

                            <xp:dojoAttribute name="skin">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "BootstrapCK-Skin,/"+database.getFilePath()+"/libs/bscke/"}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:dojoAttribute>
                        </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
```